# How to redirect error output and still be able to have error notification on standard output?

Tags: bash, command-line, awk, pipe, stderr

I have a piece of code which executes a command via ssh. The command is more less like this:

```
( cd /home/some/path && ./program ) || echo 'error'
```

thanks to this if the execution fails I get 'error' on the standard output and can interpret it as a failure in my initial code. However, in this approach I loose the error output (as I invoke the program via ssh connection). I would like to be able to save the error output to some error log file (it would be perfect if I could annotate it with some date and time by using awk) and still be able to get 'error' on the output when the invocation failed.

I came up with something like:

```
( cd /home/some/path && ./program 2>&1 | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; }' > error.log) || echo 'error'
```

It saves error output to the error.log file, however, I don't get the 'error' message.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at `tee`.

Comment: When you say you "loose the error output", do you mean that the output to stderr does not come across the ssh connection?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use 'tee' command, which redirects output to file and, at the same time, prints it on a screen.

Check out manual or [this article](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/use-unix-linux-tee-command-send-output-two-or-more-directions-a).

Example:

```
$ ls -al 2>&1 | tee output.txt
```

Above command prints directory listing on the screen and to the output.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not able to redirect the remote stderr locally?

```
ssh remotehost '( cd /home/some/path && ./program ) || echo error' 2>errors.txt
```

Sends the remote stderr to local errors.txt and the remote string 'error' to local stdout.